# Why I get @Provides-annotated error?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have already spent hours try to find in google what is the difference of my two dagger implementation.
It was implemented like this

```
@Module
class MatchesModule
{
@Provides
@NetworkScope
@IntoMap
@RetrofitModulesName(eRetrofitModules.MATCHES)
fun retrofitMatches(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, rxAdaptor: RxJava2CallAdapterFactory, iBuilder: Retrofit.Builder): Retrofit = iBuilder.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(mDeserializerMatches));
}
```

This method provide Retrofit object, also I am using annotation `@IntoMap` and `@RetrofitModulesName(...)` in order to put all of this `Retrofit` objects to map.

```
@Module
class PreviewModule
{
@Provides
@PreviewScope
fun provideMatchesPresenter(retrofitModules: Map<eRetrofitModules, Retrofit>): IMatchPresenter = MatchPresenter(retrofitModules)
}
```

I am getting all `Retrofit` object and passing them to `MathcPresenter` all is ok and fine.
But I would like to get `Map<Foo, Provider<Retrovit>>` in my presenter.
So, I added this word `Provider` to argument

```
@Provides
@PreviewScope
fun provideMatchesPresenter(retrofitModules: Map<eRetrofitModules, 
Provider<Retrofit>>): IMatchPresenter = MatchPresenter(retrofitModules)
```

as well as to the constructor of `MathcPresenter`

```
class MatchPresenter(retrofitModules: Map<eRetrofitModules, Provider<Retrofit>>): IMatchPresenter
```

And now I can not undersand why, but I get such error

> Error:(6, 1) error: [com.example.alexeyt.sunshinekotlin.moduls.previewmodule.PreviewComponent.inject(com.example.alexeyt.sunshinekotlin.ui.fragments.previewFragments.PreviewFragment)] java.util.Map> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

---

PreviewScope

```
@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class PreviewScope
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is`@PreviewScope` ?

Comment: @DivyeshKalotra added to the question

Comment: @DivyeshKalotra but why did you ask about `preview scope`? As far as I understand it is does not matter... It is works perfectly, until I add `Provider<>` to the argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a problem with how Kotlin handles generics wildcards.

When using Dagger 2 Multibindinds, the type of the Map is interpreted by Dagger (which uses Java Reflection to analyse your code and generate Component implementations) as `Map<eRetrofitModules, ? extends Provider<Retrofit>>`. This happens because [maps in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/) have their `V` type parameter marked as `out`.

[@JvmSuppressWildcards](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-suppress-wildcards/index.html) annotation removes that information from the compiled code. Just use that annotation on `Provider<Retrofit>`:

`Map<eRetrofitModules, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<Retrofit>>`.

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042989/kotlin-dagger-inject-map-for-viewmodel-factory) interesting.

Comment: Yes, it helped . But I found this solution before and tried.. but nothing... maybe in another place. Ok, anyway thanks a lot