# Dagger multibinding of viewmodels using provides instead of constructor injection

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

All examples on how to combine ViewModel with dagger2 has been to use constructor injection on the ViewModelFactory. Like this:

```java
private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> providers;

@Inject
public ViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> providers) {
    this.providers = providers;
}
```

While the module could look something like this.

```java
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(value = SomeViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindSomeViewModel(SomeViewModel viewModel);

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Binds
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory 
    bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory);
}
```

Now because I like to write reusable code and so I would like to move the factory into another android library module. So I would like to be able to do something like this:

New constructor (just removed @Inject):

```java
private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> providers;

public ViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> providers) {
    this.providers = providers;
}
```

And the module:

```java
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(value = SomeViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindSomeViewModel(SomeViewModel viewModel);

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Provides
    ViewModelProvider.Factory 
    provideViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> providers) {
        // Manually creates the ViewModelFactory.
        return new ViewModelFactory(providers);
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error

```
error: com.example.project.ViewModelModule has errors
```

### Question

How do you inject a ViewModelProvider.Factory residing in another module using @Provides which takes the possible view models it creates in the constructor?

Basically, I wan't to use @Provides and call the constructor explicitly instead of letting Dagger do it with constructor injection using @Binds here.

Comment: "New constructor (just removed `@Inject`)"

Why are you removing `@Inject`?

What version of Dagger 2 are you using?

Can you please post more of the stack trace?

Comment: @luis_cortes What I posted is the full stack trace. When I said "Removed @Inject" I simply meant that I don't want to use constructor injection because the object I am to create is located in another module without a dependency on dagger and shouldn't be explicitly part of my dependency graph. Look at the code now, is it easier to understand?

Comment: By keeping the `@Inject` constructor you are not forcing a dependency on Dagger. 
`@Inject` is a part of the `javax.inject` package which is tiny (see [JSR 330](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330)). Moreover, consumers of your lib will still be able to call the constructor normally, they will not be forced to inject it. 


"...shouldn't be explicitly part of my dependency graph" whether your instantiating the object through dagger and constructor injection or a provision method like you're trying to do, the object will still be an explicit part of your dependency graph.

Comment: @luis_cortes What I'm trying to say is I want to use Provides (and call constructor explicitly) instead of Binds, do you have a solution?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. I'm trying to figure out _why_ you want to do it this way when dagger says you should prefer constructor injection whenever possible and it's basically harmless to annotate the constructor.

Comment: I've never seen a dagger stack trace be that short. I suspect there's more to it, but I can't even try to reproduce because you never posted the dagger version you are using.

Comment: @luis_cortes Because the project I'm working on is a multi-module project (presentation + domain + data + device + alib) and the VM factory belongs in the alib module not in the presentation where it currently resides. And I'm trying to figure out how to move it, and to do so in a good manner because clients who use it should be able to choose between constructor injection and Provides. 
And the dagger version is 2.23.

Comment: The additional reason is that with the constructor injection approach in another module I cannot make the constructor private and expose the object through for example a static factory.