# Dagger2 & Kotlin: @Binds doesn't work with @IntoMap

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm doing lesson from here: https://dagger.dev/tutorial/07-two-for-the-price-of-one

When I'm changing code

```
@Module
abstract class HelloWorldModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun helloWorldCommand(command: HelloWorldCommand): Command
}
```

into

```
@Module
abstract class HelloWorldModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @StringKey("hello")
    abstract fun helloWorldCommand(command: HelloWorldCommand): Command
}
```

I'm getting error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] Map<String,? extends Command> 
cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

What I'm missing here? It won't work on Kotlin?

Comment: Probably [`@JvmSuppressWildcards`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46043372/1837367) depending on the dagger version you're using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks `@David Medenjak`, you were right!
Above code is ok, the problem was with missing `@JvmSuppressWildcards`, so my class `CommandRouter` now looks like:

```
@JvmSuppressWildcards
class CommandRouter @Inject constructor(
    val outputter: Outputter,
    val commands: Map<String, Command>
) {
// ...
}
```